# Why is it necessary to use the dot operator before the optional chaining - before a function?

Tags: javascript, optional-chaining

So this is the pic

[image: restaurant is the object and order is a function in that object]

so as you can see why do I have to use the dot operator after trying to do the optional chaining ?

I tried to exclude it but then it shows error.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Because that's the syntax for the feature.

Comment: @Pointy thanks man, didn't know that.

Comment: @HereticMonkey yeah thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `?` and `?.` are two different things. Only the latter is Option chaining, so if you remove the period, you have a start of a ternary operation.

Also note that *The optional chaining `?.` is not an operator, but a special syntax construct* [src](https://javascript.info/optional-chaining#other-variants)

Comment: Thanks for the help man

Answer (score 1):

That's how the syntax was specified.

Why? Because without the dot, the `?` is ambiguous and could the the begin of a conditional operator expression (`… ? (…) : …`) instead. To make parsing easier (not having to lookahead and find a matching `:`), the dot that immediately follows the question mark is required.